# Signalr Winform Callback

Tags: c#, websocket, signalr, signalr-hub

I am experimenting with Signalr Hubs and created a small app to push messages to an external hub. I create a proxy and connect to the hub and then I can invoke any method I want.

```
  InitializeComponent();

        connection = new HubConnection("http://externalsite.net");

        myHub = connection.CreateProxy("WebHub");

        if (connection.State.ToString() != "Connected")
        {
            connection.ConnectionId = "adminConsole";

            Console.WriteLine("Attempting to connect...");
            connection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Attempting to Connect");
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("error opening the connection:{0}" 
                    task.Exception.GetBaseException());
                }
                else
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Client Connected");

                }
            }).Wait();
        }
```

then I can use "myHub.Invoke(method)"

On my hub I have methods for connected clients and can update the web page but how do I go about subscribing or informing my app of these events?.

e.g this is a method on the hub:

public void Send(string message, string name)
        {

```
        Clients.All.Broadcast(message, name);
    }
```

All Clients receive this message, how could my app receive this also?.
Is this possible ?, I can get my app to poll for changes but this is far from ideal.

UPDATE:
I have tried to attach the On<> method below with no luck either.

```
myHub.On<VMessage>("Send", message =>
            textBox1.Text += string.Format("Message update for
           {0} Message : {1}\n", message.engineName, message.Vmsg)
            );
```

Comment: myHub.On<object>("onEvent", OnEvent);

Comment: Found ta good article here http://ruchirac.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/connecting-net-client-console.html , Thanks Anders for pointing me in the right direction.